# 64 bit by 32 bit division

Tags: c, 64-bit, math, division

I am looking for a fast way to perform the following divison:

- Dividend is a signed 64 bit integer.
- Divisor is a signed 32 bit integer.
- Quotient should be a signed 64 bit integer, remainder is unnecessary.
- **Low dword of the dividend is zero.**

I am using only 32 bit data types, since 64 bit ones are poorly supported by the compiler, and no assembly. Accuracy can be somewhat compromised in favor of speed.

Any pointers on this one?

Comment: If your lower 32-bits are 0, then you will not have a remainder anyway.

Comment: @ysap: Not true.  Consider `(1L<<32) / 3`.

Comment: I'm curious, are you using a 32-bit processor, with a reasonably _up-to-date_ C compiler, that does not support 64-bit integers well? What is this frustrating combination?

Comment: @mctylr: Have you ever worked on an embedded platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signed 64 by 32 integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089265/signed-64-by-32-integer-division)

Comment: @Hans (and potential close voters): note that the cited question assumes the existence of a somewhat unusual hardware instruction.

Comment: How much accuracy are you willing to compromise? Is `(a * 2^32)/ b =~ (a/b) * 2^32` a good enough approximation? ;-)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - yes, you are right. My mind is programmed to the modulu arithmetics space...

Comment: Thanks everyone. The linked post, unlesss I'm missing something, assumes the existance of some magic `udive` instruction, that preety much does what I'm asking for. @Steve: nope :P

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, I have, but not in the case of 32-bit embedded, where gcc or sdcc is often a sane choice for a compiler if the dev kit compiler is too broken, I assume.

Answer (score 3):

64/32 division is supported directly by i386 and possibly other machines, as long as the high word of the dividend is less than the divisor (i.e. the dividend is in the range of a 32x32->64 multiply by the divisor). If your compiler has minimal support for 64 bit types, it may be able to recognize this situation and take advantage of it.

Assuming you've already checked the generated asm and found that it does not take advantage of this, or if you know your cpu does not have such a division instruction, then you simply need to do long division like you learned in grade school.. except that it's base-4294967296 instead of base-10.

You might try reading the source to `libgcc`, since it contains code for 64/64 division for machines that don't have native support.

Edit: Actually, since you don't have a 64/32 divide operation, you may want to use base-65536. This is because naive long division requires dividing a "2-digit" number by a "1-digit" number at each step. Of course, now you're stuck doing more steps..

Comment: Knuth has a discussion on long division, and describes the long division algorithm. If you do go down the path of looking at at that, Knuth has an optimisation where you can leave the loop early. It is very hard to test, it only helps in a small number of cases and can be safely left out.